# VideoCapture cap(0) from Kinect v1 Sensor on Mac

Tags: macos, kinect

I would like to capture video frames from Kinect v1 sensor by using the OpenCV line VideoCapture cap(0) in Xcode. However, I only managed to capture frames from my Mac's webcam. If I changed to VideoCapture cap(1), I got "out device of bound" error. Anyone can help to solve this?

I'm using:

1) MacOS Sierra version 10.12
2) Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
3) Opencv 3.2.0, installed using cmake-3.9.2_0.darwin_16.x86_64

This is the output when executing `ffmpeg -hide_banner -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""` :

```
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcc1851b740] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcc1851b740] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcc1851b740] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcc1851b740] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcc1851b740] [0] Built-in Microphone
: Input/output error
```

Below is my code:

```
VideoCapture cap(0); //capture the video from webcam

if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
{
    cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
    return -1;
}

while (true) {

    Mat img;
    cap.read(img);
    namedWindow( "Video Streams", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Video Streams", img);

    if (waitKey(30) == 27)
    {
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please show your code and the exact error message. Also say which OS version you are using, which OpenCV version and how you installed it, and how you compiled and ran your code.

Comment: Also please show output from `ffmpeg -hide_banner -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""`

Comment: The output from the `ffmpeg` answer implies, to me at least, that AVFoundation cannot *see* or use your Kinect sensor - because it is not listed under *"AVFoundation video devices:"*. I think that means that OpenCV will not be able to use it either as I believe OpenCV relies on the AVFoundation layer on a Mac. I may be wrong but if so, someone will hopefully correct me and we will all learn! I think you need to research *"Kinect on Mac"* first before worrying about OpenCV.